# derivative of sinx with respect to time (t)

Tags: calculus

how does one take a time derivative of sinx

it doesn't seem possible to me, shouldn't the function be in terms of time(t) to take its derivative.How can I calculate the change of the slope $w.r.t$ to anything which doesn't affect the function ???

according to my textbook
the time derivative of sinx is
$$-cosx *dx/dt$$
how did the $dx$ by $dt$ term come ???

all answers are welcomed and please suggest edits,
and please if possible give less rigorous answers as I am a high school student with minimal knowledge in calculus :\

Comment: The textbook answer should be $\cos(x) \frac{dx}{dt}$ which comes from the chain rule. Have you used that rule yet?

Comment: I do know the chain rule.,, but i dont see why we use it here

Comment: @Paul my question is hw  an we differentiate f(x) w.r.t to time , f(x) doesn't depend on time right??

Comment: It is a function of time, via $x$. Since $x$ is a function of time, $\sin(x)$ really means $\sin\left(x(t)\right)$, so it is a matter of using the chain rule, as @Paul said.

Comment: ohh ok, thank you i get it now

Comment: @username  but how do u  know if it is a function of time

Comment: Maybe it isn't, if $x$ isn't a function of time, in which case $dx/dt=0$, but even in that case, the formula is correct. Provided you correct the sign, just like @paul said.

Comment: ohh ok, thanks @username i get it now :)